# is operator python in file

Tags: python, comparison

Just encountering this problem, it baffles me! My code just wants to compare `song[-3:] is "mp3"` which would, if I didn't use `is`, pass, but through all the patience I have with things out of my comprehension, I've found a peculiar behavior. I learned that `is` supposedly tests to see if two things are the same instance or whatever, but when the value IS the same, why, oh why, does it fail? When I test the id of two strings on one line, another line, using the `is` operator, then the `==` operator:

```
>>> id("String"[-3:]), id("String"[-3:])
(4347723880, 4347723880)
>>> id("String"[-3:])
4347241952
>>> "String"[-3:] is "String"[-3:]
False
>>> "String"[-3:] == "String"[-3:]
True
```

so I suppose my question is, why does the id change when when I use `is`, or when tested on a separate line, but not when on the same line? Is this some strange exception, or is this some oversight on my part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is` tests if they are the *same* string, not just identical strings. Since strings are immutable, Python can choose to reuse old strings if you ask for one with the same value - you are encountering some situations where it does choose to do this. As you've seen, it doesn't always. The rules for when it *does* aren't guaranteed. To get the right result in all circumstances, use `str1 == str2` whenever you mean "do these strings have all the same letters".

Answer (score 0):

It happens because when you do:

```
"String"[-3:] is "String"[-3:]
```

python creates two different objects with different id.

Comment: That's what op obviously observes. The question is: why? And why not in `id("String"[-3:]), id("String"[-3:])` case? You don't answer those questions.

Comment: Ough, sorry. Some misunderstanding from me.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `"String"[-3:]`, python gives you a string object. And if there is a same str. Two str should be the same. But if you dont assign `"String"[-3:]` to a varible.The `"String"[-3:]` will be "disapeared". I tested if you use `a="String"[-3:]`. then the id of `"String"[-3:]` wouln't change anymore